# Facebook SDK v4 Access Token Expiration

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

So I am creating an app that pulls the events from a page I manage and generates a calendar. Obviously there is no need for the client viewing this page to ever see a login screen since I just want to show my pages.

My issue is it seems all the access tokens expire, because they expect a login from the client. Is there a way to circumvent this? I dont want to have to request a new token every 60 days so I can access my data.

Comment: Additionally if the page is public and so are the events, why do I even need an access token?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. For those that stumble into this issue, you have to use $session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem. If the events are public and there is no age restriction on the page, you can use an `app_access_token` to call the API and retrieve the events.

You can do this by starting an `newAppSession`:

```
FacebookSession::newAppSession();
```

The second option is to log an admin into your app and use a long lived access token to call the API. This required the administrator to log-in at least once but the token will not expire unless the admin changes their password or revokes the app.

Once the user is logged in, you can call:

```
// get long-lived session
$long_session = $session->getLongLivedSession();

// set page access_tokens
$request = new FacebookRequest( $long_session, 'GET', '/me/accounts' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$page_tokens = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

This will return a list of long-lived page access_tokens that can be used to then call the Events API.